# Finding the maximum occurrence of a column value based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
Keyword_name Conference_name
------------|-------------
value1      | conference1
value1      | conference1
value2      | conference1
value3      | conference1
value2      | conference2
value1      | conference3
.........................
```

Now, I want to find the maximum occurrence of *keyword* for each *conference*. How can I do this?

The desired result should look like this:

```
Conference_name | Keyword_maximum_occurrence
conference1     | value1
conference2     | value2
```

Comment: I think you need to use subqueries. First subquery groups by the conference_name and then use result of it do run another query that further groups by keyword_name and count each group.

Comment: what happens if there's a tie with the keyword occurrence for a conference?

Comment: @Lamak Although it has a very low probability in my real data, showing all the values if tie happens is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    conference_name,
    keyword_name
from (
    select
        conference_name,
        keyword_name,
        rank() over (partition by conference_name order by count(*) desc) rnk
    from your_table
    group by 
        conference_name,
        keyword_name
) t where rnk = 1;
```

It assigns rank based on number of occurrences of the same keyword within a conference_name and then filters to get the top ranked rows.

**Demo** @ ***[RexTester](http://rextester.com/IDKUC58547)***

Answer (score 3):

This is called the [`mode()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) ordered-set aggregate function in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
  Conference_name, 
  mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Keyword_name) AS Keyword_maximum_occurrence
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Conference_name
```

[Background on the mode function here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).

#### A note on `MODE()` (single result) vs. `RANK()` (multiple results)

Unlike a `RANK()` based query ([like in GurV's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41814252/521799)), my answer will return only the *first* mode according to the `ORDER BY` clause. So, if there are multiple keywords that appear equally often, this answer will return only the first one. Depending on your requirements, this may still be OK.